# Private Docker Registry Garbage Cleanup

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am new to Docker Registry and needed help to clean garbage data. I have a private docker registry and have found that docker registry has occupied all the disk space.

I am following the Docker garbage cleanup steps from https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/ but getting as configuration error: open /home/config.yaml: no such file or directory.

Contents of config.yaml file

```
version: 0.1
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /home/ubuntu/data/docker/registry/v2/
```

Size of the blobs.

```
root@docker-registry:/home/ubuntu# cd /home/ubuntu/data/docker/registry/v2/
root@docker-registry:/home/ubuntu/data/docker/registry/v2# du -sh *
187G    blobs
394M    repositories
```

Docker Container running

```
root@docker-registry:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                             NAMES
e6588d7e05af   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   2 months ago   Up 17 hours   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 5000/tcp   ubuntu_registry_1
root@docker-registry:~#
```

Following is the command I run and it gives the error

```
root@docker-registry:~# docker exec e6588d7e05af registry garbage-collect --dry-run --delete-untagged /home/config.yaml
configuration error: open /home/config.yaml: no such file or directory

Usage:
  registry garbage-collect <config> [flags]
Flags:
  -m, --delete-untagged=false: delete manifests that are not currently referenced via tag
  -d, --dry-run=false: do everything except remove the blobs
  -h, --help=false: help for garbage-collect


Additional help topics:

root@docker-registry:~#
```

The config.yaml file does exist but gives error as no such file or directory.

Please help on what I am missing out or the right way to do it.

Comment: Where does the config file exist? On the host or inside the container?

Comment: Its on the Host under /home/

Answer (score 0):

The command being run with `docker exec` is running inside of the container. It is returning an error message because it does not see the configuration file inside the container. You would need to ensure the configuration file is mounted as a volume when the container was started. Or you can run the garbage collect as a separate container that mounts the same storage as your registry container, along with mounting the configuration.